# Fuzzy match of polars DataFrame to some schema

Tags: python, python-polars

How can I check in polars if:

1. Polars DataFrame's data permissively matches some schema. So all types of the dataframe can be promoted to types from the schema.
   E.g.:
   `pl.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 4]}).schema` permessively matches the schema `OrderedDict({"x": pl.Float64})` since `int64` can be promoted to `float64`
2. Polars dataFrame's schema is subset of another schema.
   e.g.:
   `pl.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 4]})` has a schema `OrderedDict({"x": pl.Int64})` which is subset of a schema `OrderedDict({"x": pl.Int64, "y": pl.Int64})`

Comment: I think all the supertype/schema "logic" exists only at the Rust level currently: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/crates/polars-core/src/utils/supertype.rs You may need to ask on Discord/Github about having this exposed via py-polars.

Comment: it depends on the specifics but one tip towards point 1 is that there are `pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES`, `pl.FLOAT_DTYPES`, etc that can help you lump them together. If you're more specific with what you're trying to do then it's possible to give you a real answer.

Comment: Thanks @jqurious! Will ask py-polars developers and will do some simplified implementation based on existing py-polars API.

Comment: BTW there are some close activities https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/1064 and https://github.com/JakobGM/patito